# How to indent typescript files in VIM correctly

Tags: vim, syntax, indentation, typescript

I'm quite new to VIM and been working on using bundle to format/colorize/indent my files. I currently downloaded a typescript vim syntax "bundle" from here: https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim.git, the problem is that the indentation seems broken for me, consider the following example, after autoindenting (gg=G) the file:

```
module Module { 
    class Foo { 
        // some string here 
bar: string; // bar is incorrectly indented
    }      
}
```

When in fact I expect the following:

```
module Module { 
    class Foo { 
        // some string here 
        bar: string; // bar is correctly indented
    }      
}
```

This is the typescript.vim ftplugin file:

```
compiler typescript                                                             

setlocal autoindent
setlocal cindent
setlocal smartindent
setlocal indentexpr&

setlocal commentstring=//\ %s
```

I tried fiddling around with different indentations settings to no avail. I am using my VIM settings and bundle from here: https://github.com/gisenberg/.vim, I sync this files on my local machine using git.

TIA!

Comment: cindent is probably what is breaking things for you. In C, `bar:` is the syntax for a Label, which should have no indent.

Comment: Is it possible to override this? Or tell VIM that < variable > : <type>; should be indented?

Comment: @JonathanNazario, just remove that line from your ftplugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Vim indentation documentation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#C-indenting), you should be able to try the following to see if one suits you.

### Manual Fiddling

> If you change the current line's indentation manually, Vim ignores the
>   cindent settings for that line.

This could get annoying due to the frequency of this pattern in TypeScript.

### Angle Brackets

> If you really want to re-indent when you type `:` use `<:>`.

This would get you the indentation, without losing any of the parts of `cindent` that you find useful.

### Change cinkeys

This contains settings that affect the `cindent` setting, by default it is:

```
"0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e"
```

But you might have some luck changing it to:

```
"0{,0},0),0#,!^F,o,O,e"
```

### Ditch Cindent

You could remove c-style indentation entirely, but removing this line:

```
setlocal cindent
```

I've covered quite a few options because that's the nature of Vim and that's the nature of code editing - you'll need to try out the options to find out what suits you best.

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin – https://github.com/jason0x43/vim-js-indent. It has support for TypeScript and has fixed all my issues with the indent.